# Consistent random number based on position (not noise based)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm looking to find a good way of selecting a random number between two ranges at a specific map co-ordinate that always return the same number, based on that co-ordinate.

In context, I have a map generator which uses perlin noise to build it, placing water, grass, rock etc, this works great, but each tile can have alternative textures, so for example the grass tile might have 5 alternative textures it can use.  I want to be able to generate one of these, completely at random, but it needs to be consistent on each play through, and without using perlin noise as this generally gives a flow (a few of one texture followed by a few of next texture etc)

It's worth noting that I can't just set a random seed for this as that part of the world could be generated at any time, not in a particular order.

I tried something like the following:

```
public static int PerlinNoiseCalcInt(float x, float y, float size, float power, int min, int max) {
        int f = Mathf.RoundToInt(Mathf.PerlinNoise(x / size * power, y / size * power) * max + min);
        return f < max ? f : max--;
    }
```

This kind of works, but this as you probably expect gives a bunch of one texture, followed a bunch of another, I'd really like it to be very random looking, but the same every time at that map position every time.

Comment: Did you try coming up with a unique seed based on the map coordinate? Having the same seed for the same coordinate should always produce the same pseudo-random result.

Comment: You could also take a look into something like an elliptic curve? I'm not sure if this is viable or not, hence so not an answer.

Comment: I can't use Unity's Random.seed unfortunately due to this running on a thread, is there an alternative?  initialising a System.Random every time is fairly taxing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "consistent", do you mean "deterministic"?

There are lots of ways to do this. You could just use any random number function, where the arguments are some combination of your coordinates.

For example:

```
public int GetTileInt(int x, int y, int seed, int numberOfOptions)
{
     return SomeRandomFunction(x^2*y + 2*y^2*x + seed)%numberOfOptions;
}
```

This will produce a unique value for every combination of coordinates and seed, but it will be the same each time. You can also look into Hashing things but that's not really my style.

Another option is to just apply a random int to each tile, irrespective of any coordinate. Then for each tile, the texture index will be the number modulo the number of possible textures, then just assign the texture at that index.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly what you are looking for, but have you tried to look at [Voronoi Diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) ? The algorithm would be something like this:

- take a bunch of random points, called seed or generator, and apply them a random texture (the more seed you have, the more regions you will get)
- for each other point, find the closest seed and apply to it the same texture

If you keep just track of the seeds, you'll be able each time to regenerate with the same appearance. You can also play on probabilities if you want to generate more often one texture than another.

Answer (score 0):

> It's worth noting that I can't just set a random seed for this as that part of the world could be generated at any time, not in a particular order.

Create a new System.Random for each coordinate, using the coordinate hash as a seed.

```
// this would be your coordinate
var coord = Vector3.one;

var rng = new System.Random(coord.GetHashCode());

// the below will always be the same (as long as coord doesn't change)
var rand1 = rng.Next();
var rand2 = rng.Next();
var rand3 = rng.Next();
```